# Provided AND Transitive Dependency on SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm having an issue while building an assembly jar with `sbt-assembly 0.4.18` and `sbt 1.2.6`.

What I want is to be able to declare a dependency that should be both `... % "provided` AND `transitive`. I need to include the provided's dependencies in my fat jar so that when I add it in runtime it has what it needs.

I tried setting `... % "provided" withIsTransitive(true)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Our current architecture doesn't allow us not to set this dependency as provided.

Is there any way to configure a provided and transitive dependency using SBT?

Comment: can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?